# How to know the status of BLE scan in android?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, foreground-service

I am working on a mobile app where I am doing the following to get the data from my sensors.

1. Running a BLE scan in the foreground service.
2. Detect bluetooth on/off states and automatically starting and stopping the BLE scan.
3. Restart BLE scan every 3mins (I read somewhere that BLE scans automatically stops when run more than 15mins). so just to be safe I am restarting it once every 3 mins.

I start/restart the scan using the following statement

```
scanner.startScan(scanFilters,scanSettings,callback);
```

I stop the scan using the following statement

```
scanner.stopScan(callback);
```

In `scanFilters`, I set the name of my device ID and In `scanSettings` I set the scan mode to `LOW_LATENCY`

The app works fine most of the time. But sometimes I get some complaints from my customers that eventhough bluetooth and location are on, there is no data update. The sensors are working fine. When I start a blueooth LE scan how to ensure that the scan is actually running or not?. I there anywhere that I can get a status of the scan running or no.

Comment: Is your implementation more or less similar to this article? : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le#java

Comment: yes. Its almost similar. But I dont see anywhere in those code snippets the status of the BLE scan. I just want to know if the BLE scan is running or no.

Comment: @MarkDsylva I have the same doubt, did you find something?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are saying that this happens only for some customers there might be another source of your problem.

BLE needs the [ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le#permissions) permission to work for devices running an Android version lower than 8.0. Higher version can use the [Device Companion Pairing](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/companion-device-pairing). You might have added the Permission to your apps manifest file like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

But it is safer to also check for this permission at runtime and request it if not granted. Have a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) page for more informations about how to request permissios from the user at runtime.

Comment: Both ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION are granted for the app. I just want to know the status of the BLE scan after I start it.

Comment: How did you grant them? Do you have a device on hand where the issue happens? If you look at the app settings, I assume that the location permission is actually not granted for these devices